# How can I eliminate the duplicate values in my answer

Tags: sql-server, sum, duplicates, distinct

I work with the `AventureWorks2014` database in Microsoft SQL Server. I need to create a view that will show the `CustomerID`, the full name and the TOTAL amount sold to client through the web.

My problem is that I can't seem to get the values corresponding to a single customer add up so that a single customer answers to a single line in my result. This is the code I have, any help would be appreciated. I basically need to show the total amount sold to clients on the web.

```
if object_id('vTotalWebSalesPerCustomer', 'v') is not null
    drop view vTotalWebSalesPerCustomer;
go

create view vTotalWebSalesPerCustomer
as
    select distinct 
        c.CustomerID,
        ltrim(rtrim(concat(concat(concat(concat(concat(concat(concat(p.Title, ' '), p.LastName), ', '), ' '), p.FirstName), ' '), p.Suffix))) as NomClient,
        soh.TotalDue
    from
        [Sales].[Customer] as c
    left join 
        [Person].[Person] as p on c.CustomerID = p.BusinessEntityID
    left join 
        [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] as soh on soh.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
    where 
        year(soh.OrderDate) = 2014 
        and datepart(quarter, soh.OrderDate) = 1 
        and [OnlineOrderFlag] = 1
go

select * 
from vTotalWebSalesPerCustomer
```

Thanks

Comment: You have `select distinct`, so there are -- by definition -- no duplicate rows in the result set.

Comment: When i run my view, i get many times the same CustomerID with different sales values from all the different transaction this one customer has made. This is what i am trying to put togheter. I need to make a sum for the soh.TotalDue for every single customer separetely.

Comment: You are using T-SQL (MSSQL)?

Comment: yes i am using transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `VIEW` using a `GROUP BY` on the `SELECT`:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('vTotalWebSalesPerCustomer', 'v') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW vTotalWebSalesPerCustomer;
GO

CREATE VIEW vTotalWebSalesPerCustomer AS
    SELECT 
        x.CustomerID,
        LTRIM(RTRIM(CONCAT(p.Title, ' ', p.LastName, ', ', p.FirstName, ' ', p.Suffix))) AS NomClient,
        x.TotalDue
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            c.CustomerID AS CustomerID,
            SUM(soh.TotalDue) AS TotalDue
        FROM [Sales].[Customer] AS c
        LEFT JOIN [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] AS soh ON soh.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
        WHERE YEAR(soh.OrderDate) = 2014 AND DATEPART(quarter, soh.OrderDate) = 1 AND [OnlineOrderFlag] = 1
        GROUP BY c.CustomerID
    )x LEFT JOIN [Person].[Person] AS p ON x.CustomerID = p.BusinessEntityID
GO
```

**Note:** You only need one [`CONCAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql) function to concat all string values.

Comment: thank you for your answer, could you help me tweak this query so that the Title appears when one exists? It doesnt seem to print the Title such as Mr, or Ms, in front of the customer names. even though it is iserted in the NomClient variable (which is french for NameClient)

Answer (score 0):

DISTINCT filters result rows to remove duplicates. What I think you want is to aggregate rows. Perhaps this will do what you want:

```
create view vTotalWebSalesPerCustomer as
    select      c.CustomerID,
                        ltrim(rtrim(concat(concat(concat(concat(concat(concat(concat(p.Title, ' '), p.LastName), ', '), ' '), p.FirstName), ' '), p.Suffix))) as NomClient,
                        sum(soh.TotalDue) as TotalDue
    from [Sales].[Customer] as c
    left join [Person].[Person] as p on c.CustomerID = p.BusinessEntityID
    left join [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] as soh on soh.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
    where year(soh.OrderDate) = 2014 and datepart(quarter, soh.OrderDate)=1 and [OnlineOrderFlag] = 1
    group by c.CustomerID,NomClient
```

Note that I removed distinct, added `sum` operator on the amount you want to total, and group by the customer id and name fields (SQL Server requires that you list in the `GROUP BY` all result columns which are not being aggregated).

Comment: I feel like this would work however, theres an error on the NomClient in the Group By clause, it says that the column name is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use GROUP BY and SUM(), example:

```
SELECT column-names
 FROM table-name
WHERE condition
GROUP BY column-names
ORDER BY column-names
```

Such as:

```
SELECT SUM(O.TotalPrice), C.FirstName, C.LastName
  FROM [Order] O JOIN Customer C 
    ON O.CustomerId = C.Id
 GROUP BY C.FirstName, C.LastName
 ORDER BY SUM(O.TotalPrice) DESC
```

Would return:

```
Sum         FirstName   LastName
117483.39   Horst       Kloss
115673.39   Jose        Pavarotti
113236.68   Roland      Mendel
57317.39    Patricia    McKenna
52245.90    Paula       Wilson
34101.15    Mario       Pontes
32555.55    Maria       Larsson
```